# Sending auto generated mail using python issue

Tags: python, sendmail

I am trying to send auto generated mail with attachment for a list of recipiant.I have written one class `Mail` like this:-

Its sending mail with proper data but sometime some recipiant are `not getting mail in proper time` and some are getting mail when i run this file.Those guys who are not getting the mail in proper time are getting the same mail after a lot of time.(it depends 1hr-10hr).

Don't know whats the problem ?

Is there any restriction for perticular domain or perticular id? like i can send only 5 or 10 auto generated mail within 1hr or 2 hr?

```
class Mail:
    def send_mail(self,recipient,message,filepath):
        import smtplib
        from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
        from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
        Userid = 'mail@domain.in'
        Password = 'password'
        for rec in recipient:
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg['From'] = 'no-reply@test.in'
            msg['To'] = rec
            msg['Subject'] = "Daily Mail"
            msg.attach(MIMEText(message))
            f = file(filepath)
            attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
            attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='download file')
            msg.attach(attachment)

            mailServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtpauth.mydomain.in', 587)
            mailServer.ehlo()
            #mailServer.starttls()
            mailServer.ehlo()
            mailServer.login(Userid, Password)
            mailServer.sendmail(Userid, rec, msg.as_string())
            mailServer.close()
```

here i am trying to send the mail:-

```
m = Mail()
m.send_mail(['mail1@gmail.com','mail2@somedomain.in','mail3@otherdomain.in','mail4@gmail.com'],'helloooooooo','C:/Office/file/myfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: Without seeing the full headers from a delayed mail, it will be impossible to debug this. That some of the recipients are getting the mail properly means that it probably is **not** a problem in the code you've shown.

Comment: Agree with @msw.  Is there a reason you've commented out `mailServer.starttls()`?

Comment: my code have not any problem.its sending correct mail. but i want to is there any restriction for the mail id that it will block the auto generated mail if it got more that some mail with a limit of time. or i have to remove or add something? I have no idea i just guess? any help will be apriciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there might be limitations both on your "smtpauth.mydomain.in" mail server and on the receiving mail servers.

Multiple identical mails from one sender to a lot of different destinations might get stuck in different spam filters.

To get the exact limitations of how often you can send mails I guess you have to ask your mail service provider.